# Position 2 image tags next to each other

Tags: html, css

I´ve got the following images in a div:

```
 <div id="desc_attach_scroll">
    <img class="A" src="img/up.png" />
    <img class="B" src="img/down.png" />
 </div>
```

At the moment class B image is sitting vertically under class A image. I want to move B to the righthand side of A. I tried to float them but it didn´t work. Any suggestions?

Comment: I still couldn't decide it yet about which answer is the most helpful. Thanks Wex :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floats should work just fine.... [See this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ju7vH/1/)

Note.. if you use uppercase characters for class assignments, you must match the case for the stylesheet in most cases.

Comment: In the past, I have noticed odd spacing in some browsers when images are allowed to naturally display inline, unless there was no space in the markup between the image tags. This may have been due to not using a proper reset.

Comment: @ScottSimpson That's because `inline` and `inline-block` are both affected by whitespace.

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply I tried to float it as in Folddle but B didn't seem to move up. What do u think could course this?

Answer (score 1):

If the width of Image A and Image B **combined** are too wide to fit into the width provided by the `desc_attach_scroll` container, no amount of flow-based css (in particular, floats) will get them to appear side by side.  You can try using absolute positioning to get them next to each other, but that could cause you some serious headaches if the image widths ever change.

If Image A and Image B are *not* too wide for the space provided by the container, they should automatically flow next to each other without any special css rules applied.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give width in order for float to work;

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cKuaA/4/)